# How to get attribute values for products in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone suggest me how to get the attribute value for products in magento, and where to use the coding in backend. I'm totally new to this concept. please post the exact codings.

```
$attribute= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

The above is the coding which i tried. Instead of $product_id i gave the number for the particular product id. How to check, where it is working

Comment: Welcome to magento. Plz tell me where do you want to get the values?

Comment: i need to get the product's attribute values, which i updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color'); // color is the attribute code here

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
```

To get product data you need to load product like:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $product->getData('attribute_code');
echo $product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); // in case of dropdown
```

Comment: Shall i use the same coding in my page? i just edit the "color" into my product id.

Comment: @Saranya This code will give you all defined option of your attribute code like color. You can use any attribute code instead of color. This is not specific with product id.

Comment: can u clearly tell me how and where to use my product_id to get the attribute values of products. Am totally confused in using this concepts

Comment: @Saranya This is not based on product id. What exactly you want to show, give your full logic in question.

Comment: actually my requirement is, if a person add 2 water can in their cart, it should automatically add two extra water can in the same brand. (i.e) he may be not having the brand in his own, so he need to buy the brand as new. in the time the logic need to process

Comment: I use the above code instead of product id i use the id number of my product. I'm getting error as " the product could not be found".

Comment: @Saranya, Match your product id first from admin

Comment: yes I did that. Can u understand the logic which i said before.

Comment: Not exactly. But I got this you want to add 2 extra qty in cart if user have same brand product with 2 qty.

Comment: if user does not have same brand as his own means, have to add automatically in their cart

Comment: @Saranya Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643734/magento-add-product-programmatically-to-cart-through-observer
You need to call event observer and check all of your condition in that and update the product qty of cart item according to your need.

Comment: I tried the code which is in the link. But nothing happens in the add to cart. it just add the product which i gave in default. Kindly suggest me any other option. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Simply i ask. how to get the product attribute values in magento. Using that how to programmatically add product. Is it possible to do that

Comment: You can get the product attribute values with the help of product load with product id any time and getData('attribute_code') as in my answer.

Comment: here attribute_code mentions which code?

Comment: @Saranya The code of the product attribute which attribute value you want.

Comment: i want product attribute value

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$app = Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$c = 0;
foreach($products as $p){
    $pid = $p->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
    $productSKU = $product->getSku();
    $bran ='brands.png';
    $gen = 'generics.png';
    $prodtype = $product->getAttributeText("medicine_type");
    $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    if($prodtype=="BRAND"){
    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($bran,'image', false);  
    }
    else{
    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($gen,'image', false);
    }

    $ourProduct->save();
    echo "done ";

}
echo($c . " product(s) updated.");
?>
```