# How to get product attributes detail in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom-options

I want to get the product custom attribute value for all the products in each order.
How can i get the product attribute value using both order id and product id in magento 1.9

Comment: check this : --https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145772/how-to-get-attribute-values-for-products-in-magento-1-9

Comment: @MohitPatel i have made custom option as radio button using this https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html. How can i get value of these custom options?

Comment: you want to get custom options value ??

Comment: @MohitPatel yes....... what i wrote in my question, i got that. but i am not able to retrieve custom option value. Can u plz help?

Comment: you check this link : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993483/magento-get-custom-option-value-details-from-option-value-id

Comment: sond hope help this : https://gist.github.com/pierreandreroy/6251977

Comment: will this give me the option selected while ordering ?? like what value selected by customer for a particular order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107033/discussion-between-nafisa-and-mohit-patel).

Comment: you check my second link...

Comment: this will give all color value. but not what selected in particular order

Comment: //"color" is the attribute_code name chnage

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from $order object as shown below

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    // get all custom options for the order item
        $customOptions = $item->getProductOptions();

        foreach ($customOptions['options'] as $_individualOption) {
        /* You will get information about all the custom options
            $_individualOption['option_value'] will show the value id of dropdown item selected*/
        print_r($_individualOption);
        /* Although if you wanna show the value title instead of id, you could simply create a method to get it*/
        $optionValueTitle = $this->getCustomOptionTitle($_individualOption['option_id'], $_individualOption['option_value']);
        }
    }
```

You can write a method to get title of selected option value as below

```
public function getCustomOptionTitle($optionId, $valueId)
{
    $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($optionId);
    if ($option->getType() === 'drop_down') {
        $values = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option_value')->getValuesCollection($option);
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if($value['option_type_id']==$valueId)
                return $value['title'];
        }   
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Note: I didn't get time to run and verify the output, so kindly check
>   for any typo/syntactic error. But the overall logic should not change. Also the getCustomOptionTitle() will only work for option type drop_down. so make sure to handle exceptions for other input types.